# EAS build can't find aws-exports

Tags: typescript, expo, aws-amplify, fastlane

I have an Expo project with AWS Amplify. I'm currently using EAS from Expo to deploy on mobile.

Pretty often I run on this error:

```
❌ Metro encountered an error:
Unable to resolve module ./src/aws-exports from /Users/expo/workingdir/build/App.tsx:

None of these files exist:
  * src/aws-exports(.native|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json)
  * src/aws-exports/index(.native|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json)
  11 | import Amplify from 'aws-amplify';
> 12 | import awsconfig from './src/aws-exports';
  15 | Amplify.configure(awsconfig);
```

But, I do have the file `aws-exports` and I can run locally fine. Sometimes I can build without problems. Didn't figure yet a pattern about when it happens or not.

I suspect it may be something related to `gitignore`(I think that EAS may check it before uploading to server). I already tried to run the command with `--clear-cache` and I didn't notice any effect.

Any suggestions about what can I do? :)

Comment: I added a feature request for the Expo team: https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/aws-amplify-integration

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `aws-exports.js` changes way too often at times and you would need to remember to always update it if you go the base64 route. Another way, if not better way, is to create a `.easignore` file and copy the contents of .gitignore and then exclude the `aws-exports.js` file.

EAS will use `.easignore` instead of the `.gitignore` and you never have to do anything again.

Comment: Note that if an `.easignore` is present, _all_ `.gitignore`s, even in subdirectories, will not be respected. Only the  `.easignore` will be.

Comment: I followed the second route, creating the .easignore file and deleting aws-exports.js line from it. The build was successful, although, when i try logging in the built app I get hit with Error: Could not find a native getRandomBase64 implementation. Validate that amazon-cognito-identity-js is linked. But on the expo app it works perfectly and logs in. How do I fix the issue?

Answer (score 2):

EAS build has access to same version of your code as it is on git.
Best option would be:

- encode aws-exports.js file to base64
- add encoded value as EXPO secret env variable
- decode that env variable back to aws-exports.js during pre-install phase `"eas-build-pre-install"` npm script. i.e.:

```
"scripts":{
  "eas-build-pre-install": "echo $AWS_EXPORTS | base64 -d > ./src/aws-exports.js",
  ...
}
```

Comment: This solution is not practical to files and credentials that constantly change or are autogenerated dynamically. At the moment the `.easignore` route seems to be the most sustainable, although it is not without its drawbacks (having to track 2 ignore files)

Comment: aws-exports is not changing often, having it in a git isn't a good thing when you have multiple environments/accounts.