# AWS Amplify clients always fail to build with Expo

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, expo, aws-amplify, fastlane

Following the [AWS Amplify documentation for Expo](https://docs.amplify.aws/start/getting-started/setup/q/integration/react-native/) with the steps below, building with EAS build fails with

```sh
[RUN_FASTLANE] › Executing baseline » Bundle React Native code and images
[RUN_FASTLANE]     the transform cache was reset.
[RUN_FASTLANE] › Generating debug baseline » baseline.app.dSYM
[RUN_FASTLANE] ▸ ** ARCHIVE FAILED **
[RUN_FASTLANE] ▸ The following build commands failed:
[RUN_FASTLANE] ▸    PhaseScriptExecution Bundle\ React\ Native\ code\ and\ images /Users/Rax/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/baseline-hhrsifdg
[RUN_FASTLANE] ▸ (1 failure)
[RUN_FASTLANE] ** ARCHIVE FAILED **
[RUN_FASTLANE] 
[RUN_FASTLANE] 
[RUN_FASTLANE] The following build commands failed:
[RUN_FASTLANE]  PhaseScriptExecution Bundle\ React\ Native\ code\ and\ images /Users/Rax/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/baseline-xxxxxxx
[RUN_FASTLANE] (1 failure)
[RUN_FASTLANE] Exit status: 65
[RUN_FASTLANE] 
[RUN_FASTLANE] +-------------+-------------------------+
[RUN_FASTLANE] |           Build environment           |
[RUN_FASTLANE] +-------------+-------------------------+
[RUN_FASTLANE] | xcode_path  | /Applications/Xcode.app |
[RUN_FASTLANE] | gym_version | 2.205.2                 |
[RUN_FASTLANE] | sdk         | iPhoneOS15.2.sdk        |
[RUN_FASTLANE] +-------------+-------------------------+
[RUN_FASTLANE] Looks like fastlane ran into a build/archive error with your project
[RUN_FASTLANE] It's hard to tell what's causing the error, so we wrote some guides on how
[RUN_FASTLANE] to troubleshoot build and signing issues: https://docs.fastlane.tools/codesigning/getting-started/
[RUN_FASTLANE] Before submitting an issue on GitHub, please follow the guide above and make
[RUN_FASTLANE] sure your project is set up correctly.
[RUN_FASTLANE] fastlane uses `xcodebuild` commands to generate your binary, you can see the
[RUN_FASTLANE] the full commands printed out in yellow in the above log.
[RUN_FASTLANE] Make sure to inspect the output above, as usually you'll find more error information there
[RUN_FASTLANE] 
[RUN_FASTLANE] [!] Error building the application - see the log above
[RUN_FASTLANE] Error: Fastlane build failed with unknown error. Please refer to the "Run fastlane" and "Xcode Logs" phases.
Fastlane errors in most cases are not printed at the end of the output, so you may not find any useful information in the last lines of output when lo
[CLEAN_UP_CREDENTIALS] Destroying keychain - XXXXXXXXXX.keychain
[CLEAN_UP_CREDENTIALS] Removing provisioning profile

Build failed
Fastlane build failed with unknown error. Please refer to the "Run fastlane" and "Xcode Logs" phases.
Fastlane errors in most cases are not printed at the end of the output, so you may not find any useful information in the last lines of output when lo
    Error: npx exited with non-zero code: 1
```

---

Steps followed:

1. Create a new project with `expo init` closing TypeScript with basic navigation.
2. Install AWS Amplify dependencies with

   ```sh
   expo install aws-amplify aws-amplify-react-native @react-native-community/netinfo  @react-native-async-storage/async-storage @react-native-picker/picker
   ```
3. Pull my AWS Amplify project with `amplify pull` making the following selections:

   ```sh
   ? Select the authentication method you want to use: AWS profile
   ? Please choose the profile you want to use amplify-cli
   ? Which app are you working on? XXXXXXXX
   Backend environment 'dev' found. Initializing...
   ? Choose your default editor: IntelliJ IDEA
   ? Choose the type of app that you're building javascript
   Please tell us about your project
   ? What javascript framework are you using react-native
   ? Source Directory Path:  /
   ? Distribution Directory Path: /
   ? Build Command: eas build --profile development --platform ios --local
   ? Start Command: expo start --dev-client
   ```
4. Add specified AWS Amplify boilerplate to `App.tsx`:

   ```js
   import { Amplify } from 'aws-amplify'
   import awsconfig from 'aws-exports'

   Amplify.configure(awsconfig)
   ```
5. Build with

   ```sh
   eas build --profile development --platform ios --local
   ```

---

```json
{
  "name": "amptest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "test": "jest --watchAll"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.4",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "8.2.0",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "2.4.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.0.5",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.1.0",
    "aws-amplify": "^4.3.22",
    "aws-amplify-react-native": "^6.0.4",
    "expo": "~45.0.0",
    "expo-asset": "~8.5.0",
    "expo-constants": "~13.1.1",
    "expo-dev-client": "~0.9.5",
    "expo-font": "~10.1.0",
    "expo-linking": "~3.1.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.15.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.3.0",
    "expo-system-ui": "~1.2.0",
    "expo-web-browser": "~10.2.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.68.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.2.4",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.11.1",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@types/react": "~17.0.21",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.66.13",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jest-expo": "~45.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: Confirming that even following the [instructions exactly as written](https://docs.amplify.aws/start/getting-started/setup/q/integration/react-native/) (i.e., responding to all prompts exactly as in the docs), plus, of course `amplify pull` (without which there's no config to import) results in a failure to build. Always with a pair of `[RUN_FASTLANE] ▸ ** ARCHIVE FAILED **` errors.

Comment: In fact, `eas build` fails even for just `expo init` followed buy `expo install ...`

Comment: And `eas build` also fails — again with two `[RUN_FASTLANE] ▸ ** ARCHIVE FAILED **` errors — without `--local` (that is, if I build on Expo's servers), at least following `amplify pull`.

Comment: I made a feature request to the Expo team: https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/aws-amplify-integration

Answer (score 0):

I've found the cause of the issue, which can only be fully resolved by a change the way AWS Amplify works.

**Issue**

AWS Amplify [adds `aws-exports.js` to `.gitignore`](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/reference/files/#gitignore) in a section bounded by `#amplify-do-not-edit-begin/end`. This makes some sense since the file contains API keys. But reasonable or not, it creates a problem. Out of the box, AWS Amplify can't work with `eas build` or other tools that use Git to identify project files.

**Short Term Fix**

Manually disabling the ignore (e.g. with `!aws-exports.js`) makes `aws-exports.js`available to `eas build`. ([Using `.easignore`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71586768/656912) is also a possibility but that [has downsides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70660772/eas-build-cant-find-aws-exports?rq=1#comment127634276_71586768) and is probably overkill.)

**Long Term Solution**

Clearly the above is *not* a long term solution for any real world project since [despite what the documentation says](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/reference/files/#aws-exportsjs)) `aws-exports.js`  contains sensitive information and should indeed be ignored by Git. Instead AWS Amplify needs to be able to work with the following approach:

- do not git-ignore `aws-exports.js`
- replace sensitive information values in `aws-exports.js` with environment variables, that are (i) managed automatically by AWS on the backend (e.g., for hosting builds) and (ii) set in the usual way in other environments (e.g., CI, local builds, etc.) by users.

As is, it feels like Amplify was architected for web hosted apps (e.g. `aws-exports.js` [gets regenerated for them](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/complete-guide-to-full-stack-ci-cd-workflows-with-aws-amplify/)) but that the scenarios for mobile apps were not thought through.

Comment: Follow up: [what happens (before AWS fixes this) if I edit `aws-exports.js` to use environment variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72241936/656912)