# What happens if I edit aws-exports.js?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

Despite the way AWS Amplify currently works, [some tools (e.g. EAS) require](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72241878/656912) `aws-exports.js` to be included in a project's repo. However in order to safely do this, `aws-exports.js` needs to be edited locally so that sensitive information there is replaced with environment variables.

My question is, what happens if I do that? If I edit `aws-exports.js` and replace values there with environment variables

1. will any of my edits get overwritten by my use of the Amplify CLI (e.g., `push` or `pull` or `add` or `update`)?
2. Will any of my edits end up affecting the configuration of the backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`aws-exports.js` is simply representation of your backend (so that the frontend can access to the backend).

If you edit it, it won't affect any of the backend configuration, and will be re-generated on backend changes.

---

It's true that Amplify CLI still lacks some features. For example: setting API GateWay authorization type to `API KEY`. To do that, you need to use `amplify override api` and it will generate file next to your API in `/amplify/backend/api/...` directory where you can override default configs.