# Unable to Resolve Module ./src/aws-exports in Expo Project

Tags: android, react-native, expo, aws-amplify

I'm encountering a build error in my Expo project, specifically related to resolving the `./src/aws-exports` module. The error message indicates that the module cannot be found, even though the file does indeed exist in my project. Here is the detailed error message:

```
Error: Unable to resolve module ./src/aws-exports from /private/var/folders/.../App.js:
None of these files exist:

src/aws-exports(.native|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.cjs|.native.cjs|.cjs|.android.json|.native.json|.json)
src/aws-exports/index(.native|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.cjs|.native.cjs|.cjs|.android.json|.native.json|.json)
CSS
```

I've tried to address this issue by adding the following entries to `.easignore`, but it hasn't resolved the problem:
([EAS build can't find aws-exports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70660772/eas-build-cant-find-aws-exports))

```
dist/
node_modules/
#aws-exports.js
awsconfiguration.json
amplifyconfiguration.json
```

I'm at a loss and unable to resolve this issue. Any insights, suggestions, or solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!